# Nslookup in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, stdin, heredoc, nslookup

How can I get result of a dns mx record with `nslookup` in a `.sh` file that it would do all its steps automatically without questioning `set type=mx` then domain. I just want execute `./file.sh` then it give me the result.

The bash file might be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nslookup
set type=mx
example.com
```

But everytime I execute the file it just runs the first line `nslookup`, and it requests `set type=mx` and domain again.

I got my answer in stackoverflow in another way with using `-q=mx`:

```
#!/bin/bash
nslookup -q=mx example.com
```

But I would like my answer to use `set type=mx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo -e "set type=mx\nexample.com" | nslookup
```

Comment: It Worked. Man youre Awsome. I was stucked to this question for 1 week.

Answer (score 1):

You very likely want to use [here-documents](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04):

```
nslookup <<EOF
set type=mx
example.com
EOF
```